# paypal IPN unique id

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using paypal to verify users on my website by having them a .01$ payment and getting their IPN information.

To prevent double subscriptions therefore, I need a piece of information that is sent over the notification that is **absolutely** unique.

I have noticed that one can change their email over paypal so, email is not viable. Are there things in the IPN that are unique and do not change over time, like by making other payments or changing email address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal provides a PayerID that is a unique identifier for PayPal accounts.  It never changes regardless of what users do with their email address or anything else.  It gets returned in IPN as payer_id.

Comment: thank you. very useful answer also for other people in need of such information.